# Related to the bankers algorithm

Tags: operating-system, bankers-algorithm

While the bank allocates resources dynamically ensuring the system is safe all the time , what if one of the threads doesn't give up the resources it has been allocated (due to some infinite loop or something) resulting in the *bank's* inability to satisfy other threads' needs ? Will this be called a deadlock ?

Answer (score 0):

In the formal argument for the banker's algorithm it's assumed that all programs return their resources after a finite amount of time, so technically this case can't happen (at least, not in the mathematically perfect world inside of which the problem is described ;-).

However, it still wouldn't be considered a deadlock -- the thread that goes into an infinite loop isn't waiting for any resource, it's just sitting there making no progress. This type of problem would simply be a... hang. A couple of possible hang types are [starvation and livelock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html), although in the simplest case if the thread just goes to sleep / enters an infinite loop which does nothing, there is no formal term that I know of to describe that.